# Find the last saved file in a folder and move (or copy) it to another folder, using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find the last file saved in a folder and move (or copy) to another folder using VBA.

```vb
Private Function fFindLastFile()
    
    'Call GetFolder

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim myFolder As Object
    Set myFolder = fso.GetFolder("D:\SF\C0T460A220000042\")
    'Set myFolder = fso.GetFolder(GetFolder)
    Dim myFile As Object
    Set myFile = myFolder.Files.Item(myFolder.Files.Count)      '<----- this is where i get a debug nr 5, unknown procedure or argument
    MsgBox myFile.Name & " was last modified on " & myFile.DateLastModified

End Function
```

I do not have the name or type of the file, but I just downloaded it from a known URL.

Comment: You are passing in an numeric value when it is expecting a string.  Look into using Dir - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Last Modified File (`FileSystemObject`)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CopyLastFile()

    Const sFolderPath As String = "D:\SF\C0T460A220000042\"
    Const dFolderPath As String = "C:\Test\" ' adjust!

    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim fsoFolder As Object: Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(sFolderPath)

    Dim fsoFile As Object, fName As String, fDate As Date
    
    For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
        If fsoFile.DateLastModified > fDate Then
            fName = fsoFile.Name
            fDate = fsoFile.DateLastModified
        End If
    Next fsoFile

    If Len(fName) > 0 Then
        fso.CopyFile sFolderPath & fName, dFolderPath, True
        'fso.MoveFile sFolderPath & fName, dFolderPath, True
        MsgBox "File Name: " & fName & vbLf & "Last modified: " & fDate, _
            vbInformation, "Last Modified File"
    Else
        MsgBox "No file found.", vbExclamation, "Last Modified File"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked wonderful. I also like the way you set the fso and fsoFolder objects, i never seen it set on the same line using ":".